# How to get the "Background-color: Background"-Color in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I think since `CSS 3` you can use the `Background` as `Background-color` attribute. It says the displayed color is based on the Desktop-Color, so it can variate from client to client.
`alert(document.body.style.backgroundColor);` returns just `background`, instead of a color-value.
So how to get the RGB-/Hex-Value of the used color in the specific element?

Comment: What do you get if you use `getComputedStyle()`?

Comment: document.body.style.backgroundColor works for me just fine

Comment: `backgroundColor` returns the background color, not the full background. And `background-color` was already defined in CSS 2.1

Comment: thanks to all, `getComputedStyle` worked for me :)

Comment: I would like to offer some advice: If you can find a way to avoid it, don't set set styles using JS - instead, add/remove classes to be selected and styled by CSS. Helps with [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript) for easier code maintenance

Answer (score 1):

Use [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
// $0 is your htmlElement
window.getComputedStyle($0, null).getPropertyValue('background-color')
```

Comment: Modern browsers don't need `null`

Comment: @Oriol good to know, anyway, I'll leave it there for compatibility